# Does PySAT support parallel solving?

Tags: python, multithreading, pysat

I'm using [PySAT](https://pysathq.github.io/). Is there a threads number parameter somewhere? Or a packaged solver that can be parallelized in this way?

(Currently, I'm using the Glucose4 solver.)

Comment: Related, but not what you are asking for: https://github.com/pysathq/pysat/issues/49

Comment: I've opened my issue [here](https://github.com/pysathq/pysat/issues/70) and there is a method to sort of do this, but it's not really universal. The trick is to case-split on `n` variables, in that way you can utilize `2^n` cores. You solve the same formula in each thread, but with `True/False` substituted for those variables, and hopefully it's faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug into the source code, and the answer seems to be no.

The only reference to threading in the PySAT codebase is some code that [checks whether the current thread is the ‘main’ one](https://github.com/pysathq/pysat/blob/b7ac61b0830ab989159a3cd37269fe97916eb325/pysat/_utils.py#L40-L58) and [adjusts signal handling logic based on that](https://github.com/pysathq/pysat/blob/b7ac61b0830ab989159a3cd37269fe97916eb325/solvers/pysolvers.cc#L1068-L1075). Nothing in the library allows the user to control the level of parallelism used by the actual solver.

The best workaround was mentioned by the asker in the comments: manually split the problem space into sub-cases that can be independently solved in parallel. Fortunately enough, SAT lends itself to that approach particularly easily.

Reposting comment:

> The trick is to case-split on `n` variables, in that way you can utilize `2^n` cores. You solve the same formula in each thread, but with `True`/`False` substituted for those variables, and hopefully it's faster

Comment: I edited in my comment so it can be found more easily because it's *slightly* more concrete about what you actually have to do